# What s the background style for the default buttons in Bing Maps for the App store

Tags: bing-maps

See attached photo, trying to make my buttons this style.
What is the brush style for the default button for the Bing maps SDK for Windows app store?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background color of the button is: #FF333333

The actually style for the button is a custom one that is defined in the map control only and you won't be able to access. To get the hover effect a ColorAnimation is being used in a VisualStateManager.